# How to get USB device descriptor by doing DeviceIoControl() directly on the device?

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, ioctl, deviceiocontrol

I want to get the Device descriptor of USB devices on my system. I am creating a userspace application in Windows(un-managed, native c++ ). From these descriptors, I want to identify billboard devices and parse billboard capability descriptor (parsing bos descriptor).

Here is my approach.

1. Get USB devices on a system by `SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_CLASS_USB_DEVICE,...)`
2. Get device path of each device using `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()`
3. Use `CreateFile()` on device path to get handle to the device.
4. Issue `IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION` IOCTL using `DeviceIoControl()`, and the handle, to get the device descriptor.

I am stuck on the 4th step (getLastError() - `Invalid Function`).
Other projects ([like this sample code from Intel](https://web.archive.org/web/20091007233417/http://www.intel.com/intelpress/usb/examples/DUSBVC.PDF)), enumerate all USB controllers on the system, root hubs, ports, and interfaces, and issue IOCTL on the root hub's handle, specifying the port number to which a device is connected.

I do not want to concern myself with the USB hierarchy of the system.
It is less error-prone and easier to get USB devices in the system using setup API. However, nowhere I can see IOCTL being issued to them directly.

**Update1**

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/usbioctl/ni-usbioctl-ioctl_usb_get_descriptor_from_node_connection):
`IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION` I/O control request retrieves one or more descriptors for the device that is associated with the indicated port index. This request ***targets the USB hub device*** (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB). Thus this ioctl which can give me device descriptor of a USB device is meant to be handled by USB Hub, and **NOT** by a USB device.

Therefore the other solutions pass handle of hub to DeviceIoControl(), as can be seen on [Line 68](https://gist.github.com/lihas/ff0ba225f578496ae006cb6eabac8e88#file-dusbvc-intel-L68) of the source code from Intel ([Linked here](https://gist.github.com/lihas/ff0ba225f578496ae006cb6eabac8e88#file-dusbvc-intel-L68)).

I instead want to use the handle obtained in step 3 (handle of the device) above to get the device descriptor. So, the IOCTL could be different, or possibly there is a way to get handle of the hub, and index of port to which the device is connected using the handle of the USB device.

The way I see it, device descriptor is an intrinsic property of a USB device, and therefore there must be a way to get it directly from the USB device.

Comment: There must be a way to do this because the USBView utility from Microsoft shows all the USB device descriptors.  It is [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview) so you can review its source code, and you can try out the MSYS2 package for it (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-usbview` in MSYS2).

Comment: I have seen source code of USBView utility, it too enumerates all hubs, controllers, ports, etc.

Comment: Still, you should be able to look at the specific parts of it that use `IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION` and make sure you are doing things the same way.

Comment: Anyway, it will be very hard for anyone to debug your code without seeing it in [mcve] form, so the best I can do is point to working example code out there in the universe and suggest that you copy it.

Comment: What exactly about the 4th step is getting you stuck?  You should include a complete description of all error codes you are getting along with an MCVE.

Comment: I get "Invalid Function error". Updating the question with more details.

Comment: I have updated the question. If it is still needed, I will try to create a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thanks for updating it.  I doubt you'll be able to find exactly what you are looking for, and you will actually need to open a handle to the USB hub device, and you probably can't get such a handle from a device handle.

Comment: I found this question. It mentions the same problems which I am facing. I will try the solutions mentioned there, and if successful, will mark this question as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007468/how-do-i-obtain-usb-device-descriptor-given-a-device-path?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Assuming you already have USB device handle first you need to get `DEVPKEY_Device_Driver` property string from it (by means of `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW` or `SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW`).</strike>

You'll receive string like `{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0010`.

Next you need to iterate over each USB hub in system (devices that have `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB` interface) and for each:

1. Open it via `CreateFile()` call
2. Call `DeviceIoControl(hubInterfaceHandle, IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION, ...)` to get [USB_NODE_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbioctl/ns-usbioctl-_usb_node_information) structure that contains number of USB ports in  its `hubInfo.u.HubInformation.HubDescriptor.bNumberOfPorts`
3. For each port from 1 (they are one based!!!) to `bNumberOfPorts` call `DeviceIoControl(hubInterfaceHandle, IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_DRIVERKEY_NAME, ...)` to get unique `DriverKey` of device connected to this port.
4. Compare DriverKey string you have on previous step with string you have from `DEVPKEY_Device_Driver` call. If they are same - congratulations you have found  USB hub and port that have your USB device connected!

Now you can call `DeviceIoControl(usbHubInterfaceHandle, IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION, ...)` to get [USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbioctl/ns-usbioctl-_usb_node_connection_information) structure that contains [USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbspec/ns-usbspec-_usb_device_descriptor)!

Also you can additionally call `DeviceIoControl(usbHubInterfaceHandle, IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION, ...)` with [USB_DESCRIPTOR_REQUEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbioctl/ns-usbioctl-_usb_descriptor_request) to get other USB descriptors in addition to basic `USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`.

For example code see `EnumerateHubPorts()` and `GetDriverKeyName()` in official [USBView sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/usbview-sample-application/).

Also I just did that in my [RawInputDemo repo here](https://github.com/DJm00n/RawInputDemo/commit/ce78df62bbffeaefa58164e57ac67bccf9ae172c).

**UPDATE**: There is easier way to get USB device number in a parent USB HUB - just get [DEVPKEY_Device_Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-address) property from a USB devnode.